# Splitting a string into an array and extracting a line returns whole text

Tags: vb.net

I have followed certain posts trying to make this work. I have a HTML page as file. I try to extract the line that contains a string and define the line as a separate string so that i can further extract data from this line (now a string) using substring command.

So far only thing i get is the whole text as foundit string.

```
    Dim Searchstring As String
    Searchstring = RichTextBox1.Text
    Dim SearchStringPlus = Regex.Replace(Searchstring, "\s+", "+")
    Dim SearchHTML As String
    Dim WebClient1 As New Net.WebClient
    SearchHTML = WebClient1.DownloadString("https://www.imdb.com/find?ref_=nv_sr_fn&q=" & SearchStringPlus & "&s=tt")
    Dim SearchIndex As String = "<td class=""primary_photo""> <a href=""/title/tt"
    Dim iSearch As System.IO.StreamWriter
    iSearch = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("iSearch.txt", False)
    iSearch.WriteLine(SearchHTML)
    iSearch.Close()
    Dim SearchHTMLR As IO.StreamReader
    SearchHTMLR = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader("iSearch.txt")
    Dim FoundLine() As String = SearchHTMLR.ReadToEnd.Split(Environment.NewLine)
    Dim foundit As String = FoundLine.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Contains(SearchIndex))
    SearchHTMLR.Close()
    iSearch = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("iSearch.txt", False)
    iSearch.WriteLine(foundit)
    iSearch.Close()
    Process.Start("notepad++.exe", "iSearch.txt")
```

Comment: Please read the description of the Visual Studio tag so that you understand why it should not have been used for this question. Don't apply ANY tag to a question without reading the description and understanding what it is for.

Comment: #BUMP...welp pls

Comment: If you want to get the lines of text from a file, call `File.ReadAllLines`.

Answer (score 0):

Now you have the lines as foundlines()

Try this and tell me if it works

```
For each line in foundlines()
    If line.contains("string")
    Dim str as string = line
Next
```

Do not complicate your code, just grab those lines, seperate them using vb.newline into foundlines(), for loop each line and search for your line containing the string..